# Using Image Sequence as Environment Texture

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine

I wanted to use the image sequence as Environment Texture, during the animation the environment changes, but its effect on the materials in the scene does not change. If you switch frame by frame, there is a change.

Is it possible to implement this through Evee? If you render through Cycles, everything works correctly.

By the link you can see problem on Video:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaNG5.jpg